# Unit test RecyclerView Adapter Using Mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

In Recycler View Adapter I have this method:

```
public void addGridItemsToView(int position, Tile data) {
    tileList.add(position, data);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}
```

I want to do unit testing on this method and check if `notifyItemInserted(position)` was called or not.

This is my test class:

```
public class AdapterTest  {
    @Mock
    private LiveZoneGridAdapter liveZoneGridAdapter;
    @Mock
    Context context;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void addGridItemsToViewNotifiesParentAndAddsItemToTileList() {
        liveZoneGridAdapter = spy(new LiveZoneGridAdapter(context));
        doNothing().when((RecyclerView.Adapter) liveZoneGridAdapter).notifyItemInserted(anyInt());
        liveZoneGridAdapter.addGridItemsToView(0, new Tile("test", 0, 0, "test"));
        Mockito.verify(liveZoneGridAdapter).notifyItemInserted(0);
    }

}
```

If I run my test cases like this it gives `NullPointerException` on `notifyItemInserted` which is `RecyclerView.Adapter` class method.
So how can I test this scenario?

Comment: I am not checking for item clicks. Please read the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because `notifyItemInserted` is final.

Mockito cannot mock/spy final methods (although, there is an incubating feature).

So, this line won't work:

```
doNothing().when((RecyclerView.Adapter) liveZoneGridAdapter).notifyItemInserted(anyInt());
```

Instead of that, it will call the real method. `verify`, will also call the real method.

As a workaround, you should create your own non-final method and have that method call the real notifyItemInserted.

In your adapter class:

```
public class LiveZoneGridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    ...

    public void addGridItemsToView(int position, Tile data) {
        tileList.add(position, data);
        internalNotifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void internalNotifyItemInserted(int position) {
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }
}
```

And then in your test:

```
import android.content.Context;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyInt;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doNothing;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.spy;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

public class AdapterTest {

    @Mock
    Context context;

    private LiveZoneGridAdapter liveZoneGridAdapter;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void addGridItemsToViewNotifiesParentAndAddsItemToTileList() {
        liveZoneGridAdapter = spy(new LiveZoneGridAdapter(context));

        doNothing().when(liveZoneGridAdapter).internalNotifyItemInserted(anyInt());

        liveZoneGridAdapter.addGridItemsToView(0, new Tile("test", 0, 0, "test"));
        verify(liveZoneGridAdapter).internalNotifyItemInserted(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: You could also try an incubating Mockito feature to test final methods: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What's-new-in-Mockito-2#mock-the-unmockable-opt-in-mocking-of-final-classesmethods